# Check if a NSMutableDictionary is empty?

Tags: objective-c

How can I tell if an `NSMutableDictionary` is empty in Objective-C?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Very simple, use the [`-count`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHCECFH) method inherited from [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = ...

BOOL isEmpty = ([dict count] == 0);
```

Comment: I want to check UILocal notification dictionary is empty or not.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced this problem. Below code is working for me on **iOS 7.0**.

```
[dict isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
```

Comment: How it is wrong? This works for me. If dictionary is Null then it works fine.